# Changing content of GroupBox based on ComboBox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` containing four `int` values, `1, 2, 3, 4`. Below that, I have a `GroupBox`. What I'm trying to do is display unique content in the `GroupBox` based on the values of the ComboBox; i.e. maybe a `TextBlock` or `TextBox` for `1` and a `Button` for `2`.

Currently, I have four separate `GroupBoxes` all on top of each other and have the `Visibility` property of the those `GroupBoxes` bound to unique `bool` properties in the `ViewModel` which I set whenever the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` changes. But I feel like there's a way where I can condense this and just keep one `GroupBox` and fill it with the correct content instead of having four separate ones and four separate `IsVisible` properties.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PackageTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType}" />
<GroupBox /><!--Change content of this based on combobox's selection-->

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private PackageModel_selectedPackageModel;
    public PackageModel SelectedPackageModel
    {
        get => _selectedPackageModel;
        set
        {
            _selectedPackageModel = value;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<int> PackageTypes { get; set; }

    public int SelectedType { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PackageTypes = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `Style` with triggers, e.g.:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <s:Int32>1</s:Int32>
    <s:Int32>2</s:Int32>
    <s:Int32>3</s:Int32>
    <s:Int32>4</s:Int32>
</ComboBox>

<GroupBox Header="...">
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmb}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBlock Text="1..." />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmb}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Button Content="2..." />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
</GroupBox>
```

Instead of binding to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`, you may of course bind to a source property of the view model:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedType}" Value="1">
```

Make sure that the view model implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raises change notifications.

Comment: Thanks this works great! One question, what if I wanted to have more than one control in the GroupBox. Like a Grid containing a textblock and textbox for one selection, and two buttons for another. Would it just be setting up the DataTriggers on the Grid instead of the GroupBox?

Comment: You could set the `Content` property to a `Grid` that contains many elements instead of setting it to a `TextBlock` or `Button` as I did in my example.